# scala script to watch mongo oplog

Tags: scala, mongodb

I need to replicate a mongo db in a production to slice to another research db but i cannot use replica sets or anything similar because these production slices cannot be stopped or restarted.

The only option i have now is to write a scala script that will run on the produciton slice and watch the mongo's oplog collection and for every new write on oplog it must take it and send it to another research db and replicate the action there.

Being new to both scala and mongo i would be glad if someone can give me pointers on how to start something like this and whether if this is the right thing to do or is there any other way to do this. My lead insists on something like this so it'd be better if someone can point me on the right direction on what library i have to look for and how the script should be.

Any help would be greatly useful for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can add a new mongod to existing replica set without stopping the existing one. Are you saying you currently doesn't have a replica set at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official Scala MongoDB driver, Casbah, includes a script for monitoring the OpLog:

https://github.com/mongodb/casbah/blob/master/casbah-core/src/main/scala/util/OpLog.scala